# Extract incoming mail attachment

Tags: bash, python, email

I would like to extract incoming mail's attachment using bash or python or any script.

Anyone has experience on such ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Python's [email module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html#module-email) can parse and extract attachments from messages as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are very vague about *how* the mails are incoming, if it's even relevant that they are incoming, what format they are in, how you want to identify the attachments to extract, when you want to extract them (ie. at or near the SMTP transfer, when a user fetches them, in a cron-job, kicked off manually for a local batch…). Please try to be more precise when asking questions.

Anyway, one tool you could use is [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/). Although it is not meant to be run non-interactively, you might be able to script something with the `-e` command line option and the `push` command. With Mutt you would have access to everything from IMAP support to encryption in one package.

Another solution could be a combination of `formail` and `munpack`.

Python is able to do anything Mutt can do, and so do many other languages like Perl or Ruby. You'd have to put more work into putting together the parts that you need. Might be worth it, though, because the Mutt-solution above really only works for trivial problems.